# Run-Time Error "1004': Application-defined or object defined error when trying to find first match in a column

Tags: excel, vba, function, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
 Private Function GetRowNum(SearchedFileName As String, SearchedSheet As String, BookedColumn As Integer, DateofLoan As Date) As Integer

Dim SearchedFile As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set SearchedFile = Workbooks(SearchedFileName)

LastRow = SearchedFile.Sheets(SearchedSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, BookedColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
     If SearchedFile.Sheets(SearchedSheet).Range(i, BookedColumn).Value = DateofLoan Then
        GetRowNum = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next I

End Function
```

The "If SearchedFile....." line is what is giving me the error, but I can't find what is wrong with it.  It states that the variables are all as they should be, it looks like it should start with column C2 and work its way down until if finds the matching date.  I tried using (Date) after .Value but that didn't help.  The dates are formatted identically, so I don't think I need to change them to a number or text first.

The worksheet that I am searching is open in read only.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?  Any additional information needed?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

The `Range` property doesn't have an indexer that matches `Range(Integer, Integer)`.  Change this line (continuation added only to avoid side-scrolling)...

```
If SearchedFile.Sheets(SearchedSheet).Range(i, BookedColumn).Value = _
                                                              DateofLoan Then
```

...to this:

```
If SearchedFile.Sheets(SearchedSheet).Cells(i, BookedColumn).Value = _
                                                              DateofLoan Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This one really had me stumped and your correction made it work perfectly.